# Angular 5 : A component with Form inside a Modal ng-template validation

Tags: angular

I have in HTML of parent component `workorders.component.html`, a MODAL 'ng-template' with a child component named 'app-generic-form'.

The component named 'app-generic-form' is basically a reactive FORM. All the validation in the 'app-generic-form' is done locally.

In the parent component (`workorders.component.html`) I have the 'submit' and 'cancel' buttons which are part of the MODAL 'ng-template'.

How can I disable and enable the submit button on the parent component based on the child component (`app-generic-form`) FORM validations?

The MODAL part :

```
<ng-template #component let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">{{modalRef.content.title}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="save('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <app-generic-form [fields]="fields" [data]="modalRef.content.data"></app-generic-form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="cancel()">{{'work-order.cancel' | translate }}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submit()">{{'work-order.save' | translate }}</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: Check this blog of [@Output Decorator](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular) If you find any diff to implement then just let us know!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Or specially [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) from official doc

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ControlValueAccessor

An example of the same scenario except the modal

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-control-value-accessor-demo-op678d?file=src/app/app.component.html)